# CMake problem finding an include file in another subproject

Tags: cmake

I have a project that we will call proj.

It has a subproject call config which does not link to anything because we want to manage it separately from the primary image.
But config has some configuration files, lets call them sys_config.h and user_config.h, that define the structure that others need to access and to be clean about it, I want those stored with the config subproject.

Finally, there is a library, we will call lib that is included in proj.  It needs to be able to reference those config include files.

So, the file structure is approximately like this:

```
proj
  main
    src
    include
    (this references and includes lib below)

  config
    src
      sys_config.c
      user_config.c
    include
      config
        sys_config.h
        user_config.h

  mylib
    src
      mylib.c
             #include <config/sys_config.h>
                 or
             #include <sys_config.h>
    include
      mylib.h
```

Now, what do I put in lib's CMakeLists.txt to get it to be able to see sys_config.h?
For example, this does not work:

```
target_include_directories(mylib
    PUBLIC include
    PRIVATE "{$CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config/include"
)
```

nor does this work:

```
target_include_directories(mylib
    PUBLIC include
    PRIVATE "{$CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config/include/config"
)
```

nor does this:

```
target_include_directories(mylib
    PUBLIC include
    PRIVATE "config/include"
)
```

My hope was maybe if I go back to the top and include the full path to config/include it would find it but it doesn't.
I feel that I must have a complete misunderstanding of how target_include_directories() is supposed to work and what it is supposed to do for me.

Roger

Answer (score 1):

With modern CMake, notion of a subdir / subproject is to be an independent library / executable. Each subproject (lib / exe) should define set of PUBLIC / PRIVATE headers. See - https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html. Rest dependent projects should just link with subproject libs. Inclusion of libs is internally managed by CMake.

Sample cmake files based on your directory layout (I have not tested them so treat them as reference purpose only).

Top level cmake file @ proj/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(main)

subdirs(config)
subdirs(mylib)

add_executable(hello main/src/main.c)
target_link_libraries(hello config mylib)
install(TARGETS hello DESTINATION bin)
```

config cmake file @ proj/config/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

add_library(config src/sys_config.c src/user_config.c)
target_include_directories(config PUBLIC include)
# uncomment if you have any internal headers within config/src
# target_include_directories(config PRIVATE src)
```

As best practice keep all your module `config` exposed headers at `config/include/config/`. This will make them to be imported as `#include "config/sys_config.h"` in mylib source files.

mylib cmake file @ proj/mylib/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

add_library(mylib src/mylib.c)
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC include)
# uncomment if you have any internal headers in proj/mylib/src
# target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE src)
target_link_libraries(mylib config)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. But I think I have a mental block in understanding the paradigm.  I edited my problem above to be more specific.

Comment: @RDFlorida as stated in my answer, you should be creating a configlib with config/include as PUBLIC header directory. mylib should link with configlib.

Comment: @RDFlorida Updated answer based on changes to your directory structure.